# Supress the word "References" with biblatex-chem

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chem

I'm using `biblatex-chem` to make a list of papers of interest for a group meeting: A MWE looks something like:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-rsc,doi=true,articletitle=true,pageranges=true,maxnames=6,minnames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{2013-8-GroupMeeting.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and a random entry from my .bib file being:

```
@article{doi:10.1021/ja400917r,
author = {Rao, Y.-L. and Amarne, H. and Chen, L. D. and Brown, M. L. and Mosey, N. J. and Wang, S.},
title = {Photo- and Thermal-Induced Multistructural Transformation of 2-Phenylazolyl Chelate Boron Compounds},
journal = {JACS},
volume = {135},
number = {9},
pages = {3407--3410},
year = {2013},
doi = {10.1021/ja400917r},
URL = {http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja400917r},
}
```

This gives me a nice list of citations that I can email to everyone, but it starts with the word 'References' at the top, which isn't needed and is just wasting space. Is there a way I can suppress that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general `biblatex` thing: you need the optional control argument to `\printbibliography`. There is built-in setting for suppressing the header:

```
\printbibliography[heading = none]
```

Comment: Opps, must have missed that while reading the manual.